# Calculate weekday from 02 date columns (included time) then return value at least 0.5 day

Tags: date-time

I'm practicing on Sharepoint and have an issue which looking for your guide:
On sharepoint list, how can to calculate 02 [date & time] columns then return value should be at least 0.5 day as calculated unit. For detail:

**StartDate**:   6/14/2023 00:00
**EndDate**:  6/17/2023 12:00

--> return value should be 2.5 days;

Looking for your support on this. Thanks.